# unable to setup azure log monitoring for aks via terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

Unable to setup azure logging for aks via terraform getting this error

> Solution Name: "logsMonitoring(*********): performing CreateOrUpdate:
> unexpected status 400 with error: InvalidParameter: Solution product
> name cannot start with 'OMSGallery/' as it │ is reserved for Microsoft
> first party solutions

```
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "aks-logs" {
  solution_name = "logsMonitoring"
  location = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.aks-monitoring.id
  workspace_name = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.aks-monitoring.name
  tags = local.tags
  plan {
    publisher = "Microsoft"
    product   = "OMSGallery/ContainerInsights"
  }
}
```

Tried updating solution name and verifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to setup azure log monitoring for aks via terraform and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

Based on the error message you're encountering and your provided Terraform configuration, the issue seems to be with the `solution_name` or the `product` field in the `azurerm_log_analytics_solution` resource. The error message indicates that the product name must not start with "OMSGallery/" because this prefix is reserved for Microsoft first party solutions.

A possible cause of the problem is the `product` field in the `plan` block, which has the value `"OMSGallery/ContainerInsights"`. A solution that worked for me was to change the name of solution_name to "ContainerInsights".

**My demo terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "vksb-aks-rg"
  location = "East US"
}
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-log-analytics"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
}
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "vksb-aks-cluster"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_prefix          = "exampleaks"

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 1
    vm_size    = "Standard_DS2_v2"
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

   
    oms_agent {
      log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
    }
  
}
resource "azurerm_log_analytics_solution" "aks_solution" {
  solution_name         = "ContainerInsights"
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  workspace_resource_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.id
  workspace_name        = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.example.name

  plan {
    publisher = "Microsoft"
    product   = "OMSGallery/ContainerInsights"
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]